# Chrome Extension Content Security Policy

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am creating an Extension for Google Chrome and I'm having a small problem, actually, the Extension works, but I don't like when I inspect it and see the following error:

Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:".

I don't know what is causing this error, this is what I have in my manifest.json:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Pokémon Search",
    "short_name": "PokéSearch",
    "description": "This extension searches for the desired Pokémon at Bulbapedia and Serebii.",
    "version": "1.1.0",

    "permissions": [ "tabs" ],
    "icons": {
    "16": "16.png",
    "48": "48.png",
    "128": "128.png"
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
}
```

This is what I have in my popup.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='listOfPokemon.js'></script> 
        <script type='text/javascript' src='listOfMove.js'></script> 
        <script type='text/javascript' src='listOfItem.js'></script> 
        <script type='text/javascript' src='mcs.js'></script>   
        <script type='text/javascript' src='popup.js'></script> 

        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='popup.css' />
    </head>

    <body>
        <h5>Pok&eacutemon Search</h5>

        <form id='mainForm'>
            <div align='center'><h6>What do you want to search?</h6><br /></div>
            <input type='radio' name='searchType' id='searchPokemon' value = 'pokemon' checked='checked' /><h6>Pok&eacutemon</h6><br />
            <input type='radio' name='searchType' id='searchMove' value = 'move' /><h6>Move</h6><br />
            <input type='radio' name='searchType' id='searchItem' value = 'item' /><h6>Item</h6>
            <input type='text' id='pokemonName' />
            <input type='radio' name='destinyPage' id='radioBulbapedia' value='bulbapedia' checked='checked'/><h6>Search on Bulbapedia</h6>
            <input type='radio' name='destinyPage' id='radioSerebii' value='serebii'/><h6>Search on Serebii</h6><br /><br />
            <div align='center'><h6>Generation (Serebii only)</h6>
            <input type='number' name='generation' id='gen' value='6' max='6' min='1'/><br />
            <input type='button' id='submitButton' value='Search' /></div>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

popup.js: https://www.dropbox.com/s/tczqpaom0igy2bh/popup.js
This is the only file that is affecting any element in popup.html

Comment: Maybe some of your scripts manipulate the DOM inserting a script node with an external src. Aren't there any more details regarding the error ?

Comment: All it says is that and it points to popup.html first line =/
I will update the question with a link for the other files

Comment: To find the cause of the error, remove all `<script>` elements one by one in reverse order until the CSP error goes away. Don't forget to carefully study the documentation of the [CSP](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html).

Comment: Thx Rob W, the problem is with the jquery.js, I'll have to modify some things in my code, but at least it won't give any error anymore ^^

Comment: Acctually, I'm not being able to redo my code without the jquery.js D=
I don't know why "document.getElementById("submitButton").click(search)" isn't working
It gives me the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'click' of null"

Comment: From the code you have posted above, `popup.js` is referenced in `head` and calls `document.body.onload = ...`, but at the time this is called `document.body` is undefined. If you have changed the code, please post updated version.

Comment: how do I define document.body? I'm new to JavaScript

Comment: You don't define the body. It is "defined" by the browser after it renders your HTML. If you want to reference it from a sscript in `head` you can wait for the `DOMContentLoaded` event, e.g.: `window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {/* document.body is now defined and loaded */ ... });`

Comment: I did this `window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
 document.getElementById('submitButton').click(search);
 document.getElementById('mainForm').submit(search);
 document.getElementById('pokemonName').keypress(searchKey);
 document.getElementById('gen').keypress(searchKey);
 
 document.getElementById('pokemonName')[0].focus();
 
 init();
});` and it didn't work, it shows nothing when I try to use the extension and inspecting it also shows nothing...

Comment: I finally got it to work!
There were a lot of changes do to do because I removed jquery.js
But it is working now and without giving me the Content Security Policy error